# how can ı one line create list with for loop not tuple pyhton

Tags: python, list, for-loop

```
a =[[(i,a) for i in range(0,41,20) for a in range(0,41,20)]]
print(a)
```

That's print list = [(0,20), (0,40) or something going but ı want [[0,20],[0,40] something like that. I don't want tuple and ı want one line code with for loop.

Comment: `(i,a)` creates tuple. If you don't want a tuple, create a list, i.e. `[i,a]` instead

Comment: Are you deliberately creating a list of one list of tuples/lists? Ie. should it really be `[[...]]` or `[...]`?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych you may be right. NOt sure OP's real intention... lol

Comment: BTW, `[0, 20, 40]` is both shorter and clearer than `range(0, 41, 20)` ;-)

Comment: @Dogukan - what's your expected output? Please confirm first.  like this - ```[[0, 0], [0, 20], [0, 40], [20, 0], [20, 20], [20, 40], [40, 0], [40, 20], [40, 40]]```  Or other form?

Comment: I take the answer actually I thats print tuple but ı want the list I am asking how can i change the tuple to list like [(20,20)] [[20,20]] and ı take the answer and ı am sorry asking bad question I try better next time.

Comment: It's better to *examine* and compare the above *comments* and posted answers - to make sure which one is you want.  There seems to be some confusion.... *Nothing to apoplogy* but better to be clear next time.

Answer (score 1):

`(i,a)` creates a tuple. Just use `[i, a]` instead:

```py
out = [[[i, a] for i in range(0, 41, 20) for a in range(0, 41, 20)]]
print(out)
```

Output:

```py
[[[0, 0], [0, 20], [0, 40], [20, 0], [20, 20], [20, 40], [40, 0], [40, 20], [40, 40]]]
```

Comment: It seems that creating too many nested levels?  Better to confirm with OP's.

Comment: @DanielHao - yeah, I'm just waiting for a comment from OP. If they say it has too many nested levels, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
a =[[[i,a] for i in range(0,41,20) for a in range(0,41,20)]]
print(a)
```

Output: [[[0, 0], [0, 20], [0, 40], [20, 0], [20, 20], [20, 40], [40, 0], [40, 20], [40, 40]]]

```
[[i,a] for i in range(0,41,20) for a in range(0,41,20)]
```

Remove one [] to get this [[0,20],[0,40] something like that

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I am sorry I try better my bad.